# How would I be able to save an integer when an app is terminated and then load it again once the app is reopened?

Tags: ios, integer, save, nsuserdefaults

I am working on an app where I need to save one int until the player decides to play the game again. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could guide me by using NSUserDefaults to save this integer whenever the application is terminated, and then be able to load it again as soon as the application loads. If there is any further information that is needed to help you help me just let me know! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save an `int`, you will need to convert it to an `NSNumber`. Use:

```
 NSNumber *number = @(myInt);
```

Then you can save it (when the app terminates in your appDelegate's applicationWillTerminate:) using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:number forKey:@"number"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To retrieve the value use:

```
NSNumber *number = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"number"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this did end up working, but just to make sure the code is functioning properly where in the App Delegate file would I place this code so that the NSNumber is saved when the user exits the app and then loaded back up when the application is launched once again?

Comment: Save the number in `applicationWillTerminate:` and load it back in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Answer (score 1):

As pranav told you can store int as NSNumber or you can store it as a String, Following will work fine with NSNumber object,

```
    int a = 10;
    NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:a];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:myNumber forKey:@"storedInt"];
    NSLog(@"stored number object %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"storedInt"]);  // retrieve value from NSUserDefaults

    //then change NSNumber object to int value - if required
    int retrievedInt = [myNumber intValue];
    NSLog(@"int value %u", retrievedInt);
```

Comment: You need to call `synchronize` on your `defaults` object. When the app is about to quit there is no guarantee that iOS will automatically save your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How would I then load this saved number once the application is opened back up?

Comment: its in the answer itself. use [defaults objectForKey:@"storedInt"]